# How to remove the entire git trail in a production environment after deploying code

Tags: git, deployment, production-environment, git-deploy

It is strange to me that I have not found anything related to this situation, which in turn seems very usual...:

I have finished a web project for one of my clients, and they have provided me with access to one of their remote production machines in order to deploy the code. There, I have done `git clone` and I have successfully deployed it. Now, I want to remove all the git trail because when I execute, e.g., `git status`, it returns the same output as in my local development environment. In others words, I would like to leave the code there, but not any git files, configurations, or tracking information about my repo.

What is the professional way of doing a production deployment using git, but leaving **only** the code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the clone then remove the `.git` directory.

Better way to do it is use `git archive` then extract it to your production area.

```
git archive <TAG> --output=production.tar
```

You can also specify a zip format. *`--format` is option. It tried to guess the format from the file name. See `git archive --help`

```
git archive <TAG> --format=zip --output=production.zip
```